# Symfony2: setting security.yml and use custom password encryption

Tags: security, symfony

I am trying to use a custom password encryptin in my symfony2 project.

I have a problem with setting the security:

```
security:
    encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
      id: custom_encoder

    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: MDPI\BackendBundle\Entity\Users, property: email }

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check


    access_control:
        - { path: /admin/.*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: /.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Here, I am getting the exception:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "main" under "security.encoders.providers"
```

Any help is wellcome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem, there were some extra spaces in my security.yml that I deleted. Spaces have to be managed with care it this file !!!

Comment: The spaces matters in `yaml` files, don't use tabs even